# How to execute code on every page load on laravel

Tags: laravel, controller, middleware

I need to prepare a set of dates and store them in Session variables when the user reloads the page. This is done from the Controller. This is a problem because the app calls about 18 different controllers on each load, so I need to change the way these dates are stored.

I've thought about using a middleware but that would mean setting this middleware for each method where I load the view, otherwise it would still be loading this dates 18 times per call.
Also I've tried setting a rate limiter of one minute, but the reason I have to change the way this is done is because the dates mix up on successive calls, and this idea prevented that happening more than once a minute.

So I was wondering if there was a way of calling a method just once per view load or something aprox.

Comment: You could look at view-composers for Laravel. The jist of it is that every time a certain view (or any view) loads, it executes code. (Keep in mind that, when using partials, this also counts as a view-load). See documentation for it here > [View Composers](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/views#view-composers)

Comment: I'll try inserting the php code inside @once in the main layout and that should do the trick. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a new Service Provider:

```
php artisan make:provider DateServiceProvider
```

2. Open config/app.php and add your service provider to the providers array:

```
'providers' => [
    // ...
    App\Providers\DateServiceProvider::class,
],
```

3. In the newly created DateServiceProvider, use the boot method to set up your dates:

```
namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Session;

class DateServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        if (!Session::has('dates')) {
            // Calculate your dates here...
            $dates = '...';

            // Store the dates in session
            Session::put('dates', $dates);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Register services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

Now, you can access these dates from any controller, middleware, or view via the session:

```
$dates = session('dates');
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm trying that setting a log and it's still being called the same amount of times.

Comment: If you have a session, you don't need to log in anymore. Because if there is a Session, the user has already entered this site. You can implement this logic.

Comment: I meant I log whenever the method is called, and there is no change in setting the dates in the controller construct or in the service provider; they're both 18 times

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel, you can execute a method just once per view load by using the @once directive provided by Blade, Laravel's templating engine. This directive ensures that the code within it is only executed once for each view rendering. Here's how you can use it:

```
@once
    <?php
        // Call your method here
        myMethod();
    ?>
@endonce
```

If I understood it right this is what you want.